# Python Serial not outputting full string

Tags: python

I have the following code running on one computer, and another computer with RS232 DataLogger by Eltima Software reading the serial connection.

When I run the python file on the one computer, only a few characters show up on the other computer, not the full "hellobob"

I have the monitoring computer set at 9600 baud rate, 8 data bits, no parity, one stop bit.

The monitoring computer only picks up "he". I have monitored lots of other devices with the same software, so I know that is working.

This is the python code.

```
import serial
import io
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-A505VSLL')

sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser))


sio.write(unicode("hellobob\n"))
sleep(5)
sio.flush()
ser.close()
```

Comment: Does the entire text get through if you directly call `ser.write()`, rather than piling two layers of abstraction on top of it?  (I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem, but the documentation for `BufferedRWPair` explicitly says not to pass the same object for both reader and writer.)

Answer (score 0):

It may be encoding issue. You may simply try following without io module:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-A505VSLL')
ser.write(b"hellobob\n") # send bytes
ser.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.. It still just sends "he"

Comment: Then I think it is not the issue of the computer to send, but some setting issue at the DataLogger.

Comment: I tried today with many different data loggers, so I think it is a code issue. Thoughts?

Comment: You may try to debug by sending 3 char one bye one like ser.write(b'h'); time.sleep(0.1); ser.write(b'e'); time.sleep(0.1); ser.write(b'l'); and see if your Datalogger can get more than 2 char.